# How do you convert an EitherT to an Either?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, for-comprehension, either

I'm getting an error because inside the for-comprehension I have EitherTs instead of Eithers. I've looked for ways to convert and EitherT to an Either but Scala searches yield very few good answers.

```
val res: Either[ClientError, Response] = stuff.proc match {
    case Client1 => client1.doTheThing(sid) // returns Either[ClientError, Response]
    case Client2 => 
        for {
            x <- getIt(a) // returns EitherT[Future, ClientError, Response]
            y <- getTheOtherThing(b) // returns EitherT[Future, ClientError, Response]
        } yield {
            log.info(s"$x and $y")
            makeItHappen(x, y) // returns Either[ClientError, Response]
        }
}
```

Comment: The `EitherT`s aren't the problem. `Future`s inside of a synchronously computed value are. What do you want to do with those, block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Scala searches yield very few good answers.

This is a strong hint taken approach should be reconsidered.

Thechnically you could call `value` on `EitherT[Future, ClientError, Response]` to get back to `Future[Either[ClientError, Response]` but now you have to block to get out `Either[ClientError, Response]`, so usually we do not do that. More idiomatic approach is to continue working within appropriate monadic context, however the problem is you cannot mix and match them. Instead you will likely have to lift all the other functions to the “highest” monadic context with something like `EitherT(Future.successful(anEither))` so that all monads align.